# Merge two Ordering Results into one result in linq with C#

Tags: c#, linq

I order two types of query. I want to show the result as one. if the first query and second query have count these both are merge and show the results of one. So i have created 3 list like **jobs**, **jobs1**, **jobs2**. I am getting values into **jobs1** and jobs2. Then i have assigned using union into **jobs3**

**Code**

```
IQueryable<Job> jobs = _repository.GetJobs();
IQueryable<Job> jobs1 = _repository.GetJobs();
IQueryable<Job> jobs2 = _repository.GetJobs();

List<int> lstId = null;
List<int> lstUpdatedListId = null;
List<int> lstConId=null;
var order = _db.GetOrderDetails().Where(od => od.Masters.Id != null && od.OrderId == od.Master.OrderId && od.Master.Status == true && od.ValidityTill.Value >= currentdate).OrderByDescending(od => od.ValidityTill).Select(ord => ord.Master.Id.Value);
var order1 = _vasRepository.GetOrderDetails().Where(od => od.Masters.ConId != null && od.OrderId == od.Masters.OrderId && od.Masters.PaymentStatus == true && od.ValidityTill.Value >= currentdate).OrderByDescending(od => od.ValidityTill).Select(ord => ord.Masters.ConId.Value);
var updatedVacancyList = _repository.GetJobs().Where(c => c.UpdatedDate != null && updateFresh <= c.UpdatedDate).Select(c => c.Id);

 if (order1 .Count() > 0)
        {
            lstConId = order1.ToList();

            Func<IQueryable<Job>, IOrderedQueryable<Job>> orderingFunc = query =>
            {
                if (order1.Count() > 0)
                    return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => lstConId.Contains(rslt.Con.Id)).ThenByDescending(rslt=>rslt.CreatedDate);
                else
                    return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => rslt.CreatedDate);
            };

            jobs1 = orderingFunc(jobs);

        }

if (order.Count() > 0)
        {
            lstId = order.ToList();
            lstUpdatedJobsListId = updatedVacancyList.ToList();

            Func<IQueryable<Job>, IOrderedQueryable<Job>> orderingFunc = query =>
            {
                if (order.Count() > 0)
                    return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => lstId.Contains(rslt.Id)).ThenByDescending(rslt => lstUpdatedJobsListId.Contains(rslt.Id)).ThenByDescending(rslt=>rslt.CreatedDate);
                if (updatedVacancyList.Count() > 0)
                    return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => lstUpdatedJobsListId.Contains(rslt.Id)).ThenByDescending(rslt => rslt.UpdatedDate);
                else
                    return query.OrderByDescending(rslt => rslt.CreatedDate);
            };

        jobs2 = orderingFunc(jobs);
      }

        jobs = jobs1.Union(jobs2);
```

and i am getting an error while run the application as follows,

**The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.**

I need help to rectify this issue. I want to order in descending also.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Job`.

Comment: Job is a table. Id, cosId, name, createddate, updatedate.....

Answer (score 0):

One of your columns in Database is "Text" type. Convert it to varchar(MAX)